# Find images recursively, copy, rename, and resize?

Tags: command-line, find, copy, resize, rename

How can I find images recursively and copy them into their own directories with new names? For example:

```
folder
- subfolder1
   - a.jpg
- subfolder2
   - b.jpg
- subfolder3
   - c.jpg
```

So I can get:

```
folder
- subfolder1
   - a.jpg
   - a-copy.jpg
- subfolder2
   - b.jpg
   - b-copy.jpg
- subfolder3
   - c.jpg
   - c-copy.jpg
```

Ideally, I would like to resize the copied images to 50px width max (smaller than the original ones).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check with `echo` included as follows (*run from within the parent directory containing the `folder` directory or alternatively provide `/full/path/to/folder/*/*.jpg` below*):

```bash
for f in folder/*/*.jpg
  do
    echo convert -geometry 50x "$f" "${f%.*}-copy${f//*./.}"
    done
```

... and if satisfied with the naming output, remove `echo` and run it again as follows:

```bash
for f in folder/*/*.jpg
  do
    convert -geometry 50x "$f" "${f%.*}-copy${f//*./.}"
    done
```

... to do the actual resizing.

To include other file extensions (Case Sensitive), add them in a brace expansion like `folder/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}` etc.

**Notice** for image resizing, you'll need [`convert`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/convert.im6.1.html) on your system ... Also, notice the above `convert -geometry 50x ...` line will enlarge images with width less than 50 and you might want to consider expanding it or using e.g. `convert -resize 20% ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have a new problem - how can I rename them recursively? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493401/rename-images-files-recursively

Comment: @Run Check there now