# Rename images/ files recursively?

Tags: command-line, rename

How can I rename images/ files recursively? For example:

```
folder
- subfolder1
   - a-copy.jpg
- subfolder2
   - b-copy.jpg
- subfolder3
   - c-copy.jpg
```

I would like to get:

```
folder
- subfolder1
   - a-thumb.jpg
- subfolder2
   - b-thumb.jpg
- subfolder3
   - c-thumb.jpg
```

I tried:

```
for i in $(find . -iname '*.jpg') ; do rename 's/-copy/-thumb/' *.jpg; done
```

Doesn't work off course! Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rename`, check with `-n` for a dry-run first like so:

```
rename -n 's/-copy\./-thumb./ if -f' folder/*/*.jpg
```

... and if satisfied with the naming output, remove `-n` and run it again to do the actual renaming.

or in a loop, first, check with `echo` included as follows (*run from within the parent directory containing the `folder` directory or alternatively provide `/full/path/to/folder/*/*.jpg` below*):

```bash
for f in folder/*/*.jpg
  do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo mv -nv -- "$f" "${f/-copy./-thumb.}"
    done
```

... and if satisfied with the naming output, remove `echo` and run it again as follows:

```bash
for f in folder/*/*.jpg
  do
    [ -f "$f" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${f/-copy./-thumb.}"
    done
```

... to do the actual renaming.

To include other file extensions (Case Sensitive), add them in a brace expansion like `folder/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}` etc.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer!